# there are three files:web.config ,web.config.default,web.config.comments

Tags: asp.net, windows, web

Can you tell me the difference  of the  three  files:web.config  ,web.config.default,web.config.comments[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obSnu.png)My os is win 7

Comment: You can get it by [here](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl). Start by typing what u want exactly, read it, try to understand, if u get stuck with some points or code post it here. We will be happy to help you

Comment: thank you for your tips.